# What does ${VARIABLE+set} mean?

Tags: bash

I'm looking through someone else's code and am not sure what this means.  It is either a variable call `VARIABLE+set` which is a strange variable name since is has a `+`, or is is evaluated and is hard to Google because it has ${} in it ;)

Comment: This notation is often used in configure scripts generated by GNU Autoconf.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It took be some time, but I found a [link](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html) explaining what this does.  It is a form of bash parameter-substitution that will evaluate to `"set"` if `$VARIABLE` has been set and null otherwise.  This allows you to check if a variable is set by doing the following:

```
if [ -z "${VARIABLE+set}" ] ; then
    echo "VARIABLE is not set"
fi
```

It is also interesting to note that `${VARIABLE+set}` can just as easily be `${VARIABLE+anything}`.  The only reason for using +set is because it is slightly more self-documenting (although not enough to keep me from asking this question).

Comment: BTW, this is not just a bash feature, it's part of the POSIX standard for shell command languages:  http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02

Comment: And available pretty much since the beginning of unix shells, i.e. the Bourne Shell.